# bigvideo.js not playing full screen video

Tags: html5-video

please refer to the following URL:

[full screen video link](http://alfiealpha.com/home/)

I have my .htaccess configured as follows:

```
AddType video/m4v .m4v
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

However the video still does not play in Chrome or Firefox. In the console there is written Video Error. In IE it plays OK though.

Can anyone help me please as I am lost on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was a limitation on my laptop. Maybe an old video card which could not render the video correctly. On other newer systems it played fine. I just added a fallback image in cases where the video is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Check Browser compatibility at

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility

For cross-browser solution, you need to use ogv and webm format too

Comment: thanks for your help. I am familiar with the link you provided. please refer to my own answer above.